# Calculate the number of selected check boxes - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have an a array of following type:

```
export class AgeRange {

    constructor(obj: any) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
        this.selected = false;
    }

    ageRangeId:number;
    name: string;
    selected:boolean;
}
```

And bound inputs to the array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options" [(ngModel)]="age.selected" class="">
```

In the top I want to show the number of selected items. I tried following:

```
Age range {{ageRange.filter((item)=>item.selected === true).length}}
```

How this blows with following:

> ncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Missing expected )
>   at column 23 in [ Age range {{ageRange.filter((item)=>item.selected
>   === true)}}

When application starts the array is not initialized. I am not sure whether that's the problem, or that you cant filter in `{{ }}`. I tried ageRange?.filter .. but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't create fat arrow functions in a template. That's the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `get` variable in the ts file and return the length

```
get getItems(): number {
 return this.ageRange.filter((item)=>item.selected === true).length
}
```

Now call the variable

```
 {{getItems}}
```

Comment: Thanks all. Highly appreciated.